# Multidimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to use a multidimensional array and i need to use each field in a foreach loop as below. There can be multiple hostname's, redcordId's to each zoneId and there can be multiple zoneId's. I am currently able to output the hostname "example.com" but am unable to use the first and second values for zoneid and recordid...

```
    $zone_record = array( );
    $zone_record["34467"]["442899"] = "example.com";
    $zone_record["34467"]["442875"] = "www.example.com";

    foreach ($zone_record as $zoneId) {
            foreach ($zoneId as $recordId => $hostname) {
                    echo("zoneId: ".$zoneId."\n");
                    echo("recordId: ".recordId."\n");
                    echo("hostname: ".$hostname."\n");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$zoneId is still an array there, and you are missing a "$" from $recordId. You would need to change it to:

```
$zone_record = array( );
$zone_record["34467"]["442899"] = "example.com";
$zone_record["34467"]["442875"] = "www.example.com";

foreach ($zone_record as $zoneId => $zoneArray) {
        foreach ($zoneArray as $recordId => $hostname) {
                echo("zoneId: ".$zoneId."\n");
                echo("recordId: ".$recordId."\n");
                echo("hostname: ".$hostname."\n");
        }
}
```